# Use Excel VBA to Extract Data From a Webpage

Tags: excel, vba, data-extraction

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to extract some data from a webpage (https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/maps/meetinghouses/lang=eng&q=1148+W+100+N). The code I'm using will open Internet Explorer, navigate to the website, and it will extract the top most result. But I can't seem to figure out how to extract the rest of the results (i.e. ward, language, contact name, contact #). Thoughts?

```
Sub MeethinghouseLocator()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
IE.Visible = True
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

IE.document.querySelector("button.search-input__execute.button--primary").Click

  Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
  Set Doc = IE.document
        
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        
'WardName
    Dim aaaaFONT As String
    aaaaFONT = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("location-header__name ng-binding")(0).innerText)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D6").Value = aaaaFONT
    
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    
'Language
    Dim aaabFONT As String
    aaabFONT = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("location-header__language ng-binding ng-scope")(0).innerText)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E6").Value = aaabFONT

'Click 1st Link
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("location-header__name ng-binding")(0).Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Contact Name
    Dim aaacFONT As String
    aaacFONT = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("maps-card__group maps-card__group--inline ng-scope")(2).innerText)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H6").Value = aaacFONT

'Contact Name Function
    Range("F6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LEFT(RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3),FIND(RIGHT(RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3),LEN(RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3))-FIND(CHAR(10),RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3))),RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3))-1)"

'Contact Phone Number
    Dim aaadFONT As String
    aaadFONT = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("phone ng-binding")(0).innerText)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G6").Value = aaadFONT

    
  IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried and it seems to all works, although I have to click a few more stuffs due to location suggestion (your initial query parameter is not precise enough I suppose).

Comment: Thanks, Raymond! On the addition of the While loop: Very helpful. I'll be sure to incorporate that. I guess the issue I'm facing (and, hopefully, I can explain this okay) is that the code I posted will navigate to the web page I want to navigate to and extract the information for the information for the North Park 3rd Ward, for instance (the top most result). But I'm not sure what to do to extract the results for say the second result (Edgemont 22nd Ward).

Comment: So you want to navigate through the wards but you can't because the result disappeared after you click the first ward?

Comment: Sorry, yes; I think that's a better way of saying it. Yes.

Comment: I have updated my code, it's late so I'm gotta sleep, please try it out and if you encounter any issue, try to figure it out and comment here if needed

Comment: Raymond, my friend, you are a magician! Can't thank you enough for your help. I was not going to figure that out on my own. The code worked great for me. I made one small changed the 'Contact Phone Number from Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, "G").Value = aaadFONT to Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(argRow, "G").Value = aaadFONT. But it works great. Thank you!

Comment: I hope you learnt from it! If the answer answers your question, it is recommended to accept it by clicking the tick beside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code works actually so I'm not sure what issue are you facing but you didn't account for the loading after clicking each link so I have added `While` loop to check for its `Ready` and `ReadyState` property before continuing.

EDIT: The code now loops through all the wards listed in the result, the idea is to keep the first IE at the result page and pass the URL of the ward and the input row to sub `ExtractWard` where it will open another IE, navigate to the given URL and extract the ward details.

```
Sub MeethinghouseLocator()
   
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.navigate Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    IE.Visible = True
    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
            
    IE.document.querySelector("button.search-input__execute.button--primary").Click
    
    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document
        
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        
    Dim wardContent As Object
    Set wardContent = Doc.getElementsByClassName("maps-card__content")(2)
    
    Dim wardCollection As Object
    Set wardCollection = wardContent.getElementsByClassName("location-header")
    
    Dim rowNum As Long
    rowNum = 6
        
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To wardCollection.Length - 1
        With wardCollection(i)
            'WardName
            Dim aaaaFONT As String
            aaaaFONT = Trim(.getElementsByClassName("location-header__name ng-binding")(0).innerText)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNum, "D").Value = aaaaFONT
                
            'Language
            Dim aaabFONT As String
            aaabFONT = Trim(.getElementsByClassName("location-header__language ng-binding ng-scope")(0).innerText)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNum, "E").Value = aaabFONT
        
            Dim wardURL As String
            wardURL = .getElementsByClassName("location-header__name ng-binding")(0).href
            
            ExtractWard wardURL, rowNum
        End With
        
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Next i
            
    Set Doc = Nothing
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ExtractWard(argURL As String, argRow As Long)
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.navigate argURL
    IE.Visible = True
    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
            
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document
            
    'Contact Name
    Dim aaacFONT As String
    aaacFONT = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("maps-card__group maps-card__group--inline ng-scope")(2).innerText)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(argRow, "H").Value = aaacFONT
    
    'Contact Name Function
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(argRow, "F").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LEFT(RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3),FIND(RIGHT(RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3),LEN(RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3))-FIND(CHAR(10),RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3))),RIGHT(RC[2],LEN(RC[2])-FIND(CHAR(10),RC[2])-3))-1)"
    
    'Contact Phone Number
    Dim aaadFONT As String
    aaadFONT = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("phone ng-binding")(0).innerText)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(argRow, "G").Value = aaadFONT
        
    Set Doc = Nothing
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```