# Extract financial data from webpage to Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to extract data from Yahoo Finance, of how the various stock indices are performing, into Excel.

The code and help videos I found online use Internet Explorer.
As Internet Explorer is no longer available, I tried to modify the code to use Google Chrome as the browser.

How can I extract the historical data of how the multiple stock indices have performed every week?
And can the macro be in such a way that it can extract data from multiple webpages at once?

Example links:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/INDEX?p=INDEX&.tsrc=fin-srch
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VOO?p=VOO&.tsrc=fin-srch

Code found online:
[Guide to Extracting Website Data by Using Excel VBA](https://oxylabs.io/blog/web-scraping-excel-vba)
[Use Excel VBA to Extract Data From a Webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68805987/use-excel-vba-to-extract-data-from-a-webpage)

Comment: Im not really into vba, so I can't answer your question how you would like it. But if this is just for yourself, you could use **Microsoft Power Automate Desktop**. Its easy to use, and also to change - if needed. It basically can write the data to your exel file - at an interval of your choice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example … it is not supposed to be a free code service. That been said, maybe you get lucky and someone will provide you the code anyhow. Good luck!

Comment: Take a look at Power Query , which can connect to API's and can be set to refresh data on opening or at set time intervals. It would be possible to create multiple queries and combine them. A much better solution than trying to adapt VBA.

Answer (score 1):

VBA might not be the best tool. Anyway, just for fun, i've wrote down a really blunt code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Download()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim StrURL As String
    Dim StrResult As String
    Dim StrMessageTitle As String
    Dim StrMessageContent As String
    Dim VarResult() As Variant
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim DblCounter As Double
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngResult = Range("A1")
    
    'YOU CAN SET HERE THE LINK TO THE CHOSEN PAGE. _
    THESE ARE THE LINKS FOR YOUR EXAMPLES (THE SECOND ONE IS TURNED OFF). _
    YOU CAN FIND THEM BY SEARCHING THE CONSOLE OF YOUR BROWSER OPENED ON THE GIVEN PAGE.
    StrURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VOO?p=VOO&.tsrc=fin-srch"
    'StrURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/INDEX?p=INDEX&.tsrc=fin-srch&guccounter=1"
    
    'Clear the column of RngResult.
    RngResult.EntireColumn.ClearContents
    
    'Setting the request.
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", StrURL, False
    
    'Sendig the request.
    xmlhttp.send
    
    'Checking if there was a response.
    If xmlhttp.responseText <> "" Then
        
        'Example of single data extractions.
        StrMessageTitle = Split(xmlhttp.responseText, "<title>")(1)
        StrMessageTitle = Split(StrMessageTitle, "</title>")(0)
        StrMessageTitle = HtmlDecode(StrMessageTitle)
        
        StrMessageContent = Split(xmlhttp.responseText, "<fin-streamer class=""Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)""")(1)
        StrMessageContent = Split(StrMessageContent, "</fin-streamer>")(0)
        StrMessageContent = Split(StrMessageContent, ">")(1)
        
        MsgBox StrMessageContent, vbOKOnly, StrMessageTitle
        
        
        'Reporting the entire response.
        StrResult = xmlhttp.responseText
        
        ReDim VarResult(1 To UBound(Split(StrResult, ">")), 1 To 1)
        
        For DblCounter = 0 To UBound(Split(StrResult, ">")) - 1
            
            VarResult(DblCounter + 1, 1) = Split(StrResult, ">")(DblCounter) & ">"
            
        Next
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        For DblCounter = 1 To UBound(VarResult)
            
            RngResult.Offset(DblCounter - 1, 0).Value2 = VarResult(DblCounter, 1)
            
        Next
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End If
    
End Sub
Function HtmlDecode(str)
    Dim dom

    Set dom = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    dom.Open
    dom.Write str
    dom.Close
    HtmlDecode = dom.body.innerText
    
End Function
```

You'll need the Microsoft XML v6.0 reference.

**Credits:** the function `HtmlDecode` was created by trincot and published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268605/decode-html-entities-into-plain-text).

Comment: it is showing an error in this line of code - RngResult.Offset(DblCounter - 1, 0).Value2 = VarResult(DblCounter, 1), shows Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Ah, ye. It's probably because the line to be reported starts with a `=`. To solve this just set the entire column as text. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: sorry to ask this silly question, but how do I do that?

Comment: Check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-text-583160db-936b-4e52-bdff-6f1863518ba4). Just click on the column A header to select the whole column and then change the format to text.

Comment: All the data in Excel is coming as like links or codes not as the data from the web

Comment: And is it possible to make it that between evry week's data there are 3 blank rows?

Comment: The data you are seeing are the HTML code that makes the page. The information you are looking for are there to be extracted. In the first part of the code (check the comments to the code) i've basically shown you an example of extraction of data from that page. Specifically the value and the "title" of the page which are saved as string variables and presented to the user in a message box. You can use a similar method to extract the data you actually want and play with them. You can try and once you are stucked you might pose an actual question on this very web site.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I think, but the table isn't being parsed correctly.

Sub ImportStockIndexData()
Dim i As Integer
Dim indexTickers() As Variant
Dim indexData As Variant
Dim dataRange As Range

```
' Define the ticker symbols for the stock indexes
indexTickers = Array("^GSPC", "^IXIC", "^DJI") ' Example tickers

' Set the range where the data will be imported
Set dataRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

' Loop through each ticker symbol
For i = LBound(indexTickers) To UBound(indexTickers)
    ' Assemble the URL for the Yahoo Finance page of the stock index
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & indexTickers(i) & "/history?p=" & indexTickers(i)
    
    ' Create a new instance of Internet Explorer
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False ' Set to True for debugging purposes
    
    ' Navigate to the Yahoo Finance page
    IE.Navigate url
    
    ' Wait for the page to load
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ' Get the table containing the historical data
    Dim table As Object
    Set table = IE.Document.getElementById("mrt-node-Col1-1-HistoricalDataTable")
    
    ' Check if the table exists
    If Not table Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the data from the table
        indexData = table.outerHTML
        
        ' Import the data into Excel
        dataRange.Value = indexData
        
        ' Move the data range to the next column
        Set dataRange = dataRange.Offset(0, 1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Table not found for ticker " & indexTickers(i)
    End If
    
    ' Close Internet Explorer
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    
    ' Wait for a moment before processing the next ticker
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Next i
End Sub
```

Remember, under Tools > References, set a reference to 'Microsoft Internet Controls'.

[image]